# Stopping InkCanvas from resizing while drawing

Tags: wpf, resize, inkcanvas

In my application, I have an `InkCanva`s with an image in the background. When I draw on the `InkCanvas` to the bottom or left edge, the `InkCanvas` changes size to fit the sketch, which messes up the rendering of the image in the background. How do I stop the `InkCanvas` from resizing when strokes are applied outside its current size?

Current XAML:

```
<InkCanvas x:Name="DrawingArea"
           Width="Auto"
           Height="Auto"
           ClipToBounds="True"
           Background="{x:Null}" />
```

- Background is set in code-behind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without specifying a specific size, I found that binding the `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` to the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the parent element keeps the `InkCanvas` from expanding outside the element.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <InkCanvas x:Name="DrawingArea"
               MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
               MaxHeight="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
               Background="{x:Null}" />
    ...
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hardcode the widths instead of using auto:
Width = "200"
Height = "200"

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to, in this case.